# Javascript file is not listing in fire bug

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a asp.net application.I added a script file in my master page.

`<script type="text/javascript" 
src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/Notification.js")%>"></script>`

But am not able to find the same on my fire bug. I had checked with another machine also.

Any one have any idea about the strange issue? If i went wrong any where please do help me to sort it out.

Comment: Are you sure the src location is correct ?

Comment: Yup. i am able to browse from my browser.`http://local.site.com/Scripts/Notification.js` by this way

Comment: I had tried but not working. still same issue persistent.

Comment: even if the src location is invalid,you can still see the script tag in firebug.but when you expand it, it would give 404 error. can u verify this once

Comment: Yup. I had i don't have any console error like you mentioned.If i try to call a `function()` in my missing java script then it through a `reference error`

Comment: so you mean you can see the notification.js loaded successfully in firebug ?

Comment: nop. that's my issue. it's neither loaded nor getting error :(

Comment: have you tried escaping the semicolon within **Page.ResolveClientUrl()** ?

Comment: where i have semicolon in this code i didn't get you?

Comment: sorry i meant double quotes just escape it like this `src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl(\"~/Scripts/Notification.js\")%>">`

Comment: It's not working giving me compilation errors.

Comment: Probably just a bug in Firebug. Where is this script located? If outise the `<html>` and `</html>` tags it might explain what you see. Anyway, if you put `alert('hello');` in that file, do you see the alert showing?

Comment: woo i found the error.Solved thank you guys.

Comment: `<` missing in the reference just above notification i had explained in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script reference just above the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/Notification.js")%>"></script>
```

Missing close tag.But still am wondering why no error was not thrown in browser while loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/Custom/Publish/Global.js")%>"</script>
```

Now changed in to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/Custom/Publish/Global.js")%>"></script>
```

Now am able to get the script on my fire bug.

`>` is missing Resolved.